# Batch FOR cycle with string iterate

Tags: batch-file

How could I make for cycle that could iterate string values with for cycle like logic presented:

```
set list[0]="string1"
set list[1]="string2"
...
set list[10]="string10"

for n in list do (

   for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "list[n]" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (   
      if /I "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (    
          net stop list[n]    
          net start list[n]   )   
      else( ) )
    )
```

Comment: The `for` command is overloaded. See `For /?` to see how to generate a list of numbers.

Comment: You could try the `Set` command, e.g. `For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%A In ('Set list[ 2^>Nul') Do Echo Name=%%A, Value=%%B`. As the `Set` command lists everything in the environment which begins with the string, `list[`, it is recommended that you undefine any possible existing ones at the outset: `For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('Set list[ 2^>Nul') Do Set "%%A="`. Also, since you're using `SC.exe` to query, why not use it to start/stop instead of `Net.exe`?

Comment: Also findstr in default regex mode will ignore spaces in the search string.

Comment: If you know the number of `list[]` items in advance, you could do `for /L %%I in (0,1,%COUNT%) do ( ... )`; if not, follow Compo's comment, but regard that `set list[` returns the items alphabetically sorted, which means you will get them like `list[0]`, `list[1]`, `list[10]`, `list[2]`, etc. By the way, change `findstr "        STATE"` to `findstr /C:"        STATE"` to include the spaces in the search string...

Comment: Of course it may be reasonable to just use `Find " STATE "` or even check for both strings at the same time, `FindStr "STATE.*RUNNING"`. Why are you asking `net` to `stop` the service if it isn't `running`? I'm aware that the service could be in a pending state, but if asking it to stop without knowing what that state is seems more than a little heavy handed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking some of the hints into code,

- I use a list index with two places to overcome possible sorting issues.
- To also avoid delayed expansion issues in a "single" command I enumerate the services the same way as initializing the list.
- for testing the net stop/start commands are only echoed.
- so I can use real service names from my system.

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\07\25\SO_51512357.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:: initialize/clear list
For /F "delims==" %%A in ('2^>Nul set list[') do Set "%%A="

:: use self expanding code to set list to array list[xx]
Set i=99
Set "list=,WPDBusEnum,WpnService,wscsvc,WSearch,wuauserv,WwanSvc"
Set "list=%list%,xbgm,XblAuthManager,XblGameSave,XboxGipSvc,XboxNetApiSvc"
Set "list=%list:,="&Set /a i+=1&Set "list[!i:~-2!]=%"
Set list

:: technically the following is one line, line breaks inserted where possible. 
For /F "tokens=2delims==" %%n in (
  '2^>Nul set list['
) do  for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in (
  'sc query "%%n" 2^>Nul ^| findstr /C:"        STATE              :"'
) do if /I "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (    
    echo net stop    %%n    
    echo net start   %%n
) else ( 
    echo svc running %%n
)
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\07\25\SO_51512357.cmd
list[00]=WPDBusEnum
list[01]=WpnService
list[02]=wscsvc
list[03]=WSearch
list[04]=wuauserv
list[05]=WwanSvc
list[06]=xbgm
list[07]=XblAuthManager
list[08]=XblGameSave
list[09]=XboxGipSvc
list[10]=XboxNetApiSvc
net stop    WPDBusEnum
net start   WPDBusEnum
svc running WpnService
svc running wscsvc
svc running WSearch
net stop    wuauserv
net start   wuauserv
net stop    WwanSvc
net start   WwanSvc
net stop    xbgm
net start   xbgm
net stop    XblAuthManager
net start   XblAuthManager
net stop    XblGameSave
net start   XblGameSave
net stop    XboxGipSvc
net start   XboxGipSvc
net stop    XboxNetApiSvc
net start   XboxNetApiSvc
```